# Running gatlingtest from gradle

Tags: gatling

I have created a build.gradle file and in it i have this dep. 
compile 'io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:2.1.7'

I have also created a simulation

```
package simulations

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._


class LukeSimulation extends Simulation {

  val httpConf = http
    .baseURL("http://--------:8295/") // Here is the root for all relative URLs
    .doNotTrackHeader("1")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0")

  val headers_10 = Map("Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") // Note the headers specific to a given request

  val scn = scenario("TotalUsage") // A scenario is a chain of requests and pauses
    .exec(http("Usage")
        .get("/api/v1/account/10186413349/totalusage"))

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(700),
                    rampUsers(100000) over(30 minutes),
                    constantUsersPerSec(200) during(10 minutes),
                    rampUsersPerSec(200) to(1000) during(10 minutes)
                    ).protocols(httpConf))
  //setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(500) over(30 seconds)).protocols(httpConf))
  //assertThat(global.failedRequests.count.is(0))

}
```

How do i execute it with gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Create task like this -

```
task gatling() << {
    javaexec {
        main = 'io.gatling.app.Gatling'
        classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
        args('--simulation',
                "simulations.LukeSimulation",
                '--results-folder',
                file('build/reports/gatling').absolutePath,
                '--mute')
        environment(['appUrl': appUrl])
        systemProperties(['gatling.core.directory.binaries': sourceSets.test.output.classesDir])
    }
}
```

If you want to pass parameter to your gatling you can do this way.

```
def getAppUrl() {
    def appUrl = System.getProperty('appUrl')
    appUrl ?: 'http://localhost:8295'
}
```

Command will be `gradle gatling -DappUrl=http://localhost:8000`

If you do not pass the appUrl then it will default to what is written in the getAppUrl method.

To use the property in your gatling code do this

```
val appUrl = getenv("appUrl")
```